# innerHTML doesn't fill parent

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

I'm trying to load an html page inside a div. It works well, except that the "loaded" page only fills a small portion of the parent.

This is the function that loads the HTML:

```
function load_inner() {
    Content.innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="page_test.html"></object>';
}
```

The **div** that is to be filled is 500*200px.

The page that is loaded is supposed to fill the parent, but in this case the **inner div** is set to 1000*500px for testing purposes (the parent has the **overflow** property set to **hidden**).

This is the page that loads the content (everything is surrounded by the **html** tag):

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.23.1" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #Content { width:500px; height:200px; background:orange; overflow:hidden;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function load_inner() { 
            Content.innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="page_test.html"></object>';
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="load_inner()">
    <div id="Content"></div>
</body>
```

This is the page that is loaded (everything is surrounded by the **html** tag):

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.23.1" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #Cont { background:yellow; }
        body { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Cont">
        <span>IM A TEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEST</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is the result:

[image: Bad result]

I've made some tests and it seems that this only happens with the **object** tag.

This works ok (the content is not "limited"):

```
Content.innerHTML='g...g';
```

[image: String set directly]

If I send a GET request to the target page and set the innerHTML to the "responseText" it displays correctly:

```
function load_home() {         
     var url = "http://localhost/inner_load/page_test.html";
     var method = "GET";
     var async = true;
     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     request.onload = function () {
        var data = request.responseText;
        Content.innerHTML=request.responseText;
     }
     request.open(method, url, async);
     request.send();
  }
```

[image: Loaded via http request]

What is the problem with the **object** tag and how can this be solved? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried styling the object tag to be 100%?

Comment: You don't show any HTML that has an `<object>` tag in it.  That leaves me confused.

Comment: @bensonsearch Yes I did: `NOTE: I can set the object tag to be 100% w&h of the parent (via css) and it fills it completely, but those scrollbars are still displayed.`

Comment: @jfriend00 It is set inside the javascript function `load_inner()`, it's at the top of the page

Comment: @arielnmz also set the overflow of the object to hidden, will make the scroll bars go away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the width of the object to 100% that 100% reflects the width of the parent div (orange) not the content that is loaded - so you are loading a 1000px div into a 500px (100% of its parent) object tag. If you do not want scroll bars you need to size the object to be the same size as the content you are loading into it ie 1000px. So the answer is that there is nothing wrong with the object tag.

example:

```
  <div id="content"> //500px
    <object> //at 100% it is also 500px
       <div>Loaded content</div> //this is 1000px and hence the scrollbar on a parent object
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok. I set it to 100% for testing purposes. Thank you for pointing that out I'll fix the post. The problem is when I don't specify neither the object size nor the "loaded div" size. The object tag is always resized to about 150*100px and scrollbars are added (if the loaded content is bigger). This doesn't happen if I send a GET request and load the page via the XMLHttpRequest() object, although an object tag is not used in the latter.

Comment: if you don't use the object tag (recommended) - you will have no problems. Object implementation is still a bit different from browser to browser

Comment: Thank you. I was expecting some more insight but I think there's not much to be said about it. Thanks again!